# Отмена push --force

Tags: git, git-push

Я знаю, что если я делал сам `push --force`, то у меня есть инфа о последнем коммите на удаленном репозитории, до того как я его перетер. И можно сделать `push --force` этого коммита. А если `push --force` выполнял не я, то как мне вернуться к первоначальному состоянию?

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog` - тут можно посмотреть ссылки на все коммиты, даже те которые удалены. А после этого просто переключиться на нужный или черрипикнуть его сверху.

Comment: пробовал, до этого я делал squash до двух коммитов - самого первого и последнего и push force, сев за другой комп, клонировал проект с гитхаба и он мне показал лишь этих 2 коммита

Comment: @ШаховГлеб кажется удаленные коммиты не копируются на удаленный сервер. Тогда только с того компа смотреть где они были сделаны. Иначе никак (вроде).

Comment: а сам гитхаб не хранит инфу?

Comment: @ШаховГлеб
> кажется удаленные коммиты не копируются на удаленный сервер